# Filed a column Period with View from a start and end Date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a View that  select Values from table A

```
    `SELECT 
     A.[Source]
    ,cast([ID] as varchar) AS ID 
    ,CASE
           WHEN  A.Source='1' THEN 'A'
           ELSE 'R' 
      END AS 'Type'
    ,[StartDate]
    ,[StartPeriod]
    ,[EndDate]
    ,[EndPeriod]
    ,[StatusDescription] 
    FROM [dbo].[A]
```

they ask me two do some transformation like in this algorithm :

if source = 8 then

- Split the initial record into as many lines as there are days
- A.StartPeriod = "AM" from the second until the last record.
- A.EndPeriod = "PM" except for the last ONE.

for exemple if :

An Employee X  has start date : **StartDate         StartPeriode    EndDate**
26/04/2021 9:00:00   AM         28/04/2021  9:00:00

it will be

```
       26/04/2021 9:00:00     AM        26/04/2021 9:00:00 
       27/04/2021 9:00:00     AM        27/04/2021 9:00:00   
       28/04/2021 9:00:00     AM        28/04/2021 9:00:00
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, what does `A.StartPeriod = "AM" from the second until the last record.   A.EndPeriod = "PM" except for the last ONE.` mean? And can you give some sample input and expected output for `PM`?

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE is a simple way to do this using standard(ish) SQL:

```
with cte as (
      select employee, startdate, enddate
      from t
      union all
      select employee, dateadd(day, 1, startdate), enddate
      from cte
      where startdate < enddate
     )
select *
from cte;
```

If there are more than 100 days for a given employee, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but  in a view i could not use with cte table

Comment: @nada . . . Of course you can use a CTE in a view.  I'm not sure what your comment refers to.  Here is an example:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9255682766d4b207a5e568b0488e65e.

Comment: thanks! based on your code i develop CTE and there is an new parametres                                     but i can not use it with the view    `SELECT 
     A.[Source]
    ,cast([ID] as varchar) AS ID 
    ,CASE
           WHEN  A.Source='1' THEN 'A'
           ELSE 'R' 
      END AS 'Type'
    ,[StartDate]   - i must add it here 
    ,[StartPeriod]
    ,[EndDate]
    ,[EndPeriod]
    ,[StatusDescription] 
    FROM [dbo].[A]